# Feign Client does not resolve Query parameter

Tags: java, http, feign

Here is my interface:

```
public interface SCIMServiceStub {
    @RequestLine("GET /Users/{id}")
    SCIMUser getUser(@Param("id") String id);

    @RequestLine("GET /Groups?filter=displayName+Eq+{roleName}")
    SCIMGroup isValidRole(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
}
```

Here `getUser` call works fine.

But `isValidRole` is not working properly as the request is eventually sent like this.

```
/Groups?filter=displayName+Eq+{roleName}
```

Here `{roleName}` is not resolved.

What am I missing here? Appreciate some help, as I'm clueless at this point.

**Edit**: One more question: Is there a way to avoid automatic url encoding of query parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be caused by a bug that is already opened - https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/424

Like in comments, you can define your own `Param.Expander` something like below as a workaround.

```
@RequestLine("GET /Groups?filter={roleName}")
String isValidRole(@Param(value = "roleName", expander = PrefixExpander.class) String roleName);

static final class PrefixExpander implements Param.Expander {
    @Override
    public String expand(Object value) {
        return "displayName+Eq+" + value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

As the recent(2019.04) [open feign issue](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/pull/667) and [spring doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-openfeign/2.1.0.RELEASE/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_querymap_support) say：

> The OpenFeign @QueryMap annotation provides support for POJOs to be used as GET parameter maps.
>
> Spring Cloud OpenFeign provides an equivalent @SpringQueryMap annotation, which is used to annotate a POJO or Map parameter as a query parameter map since 2.1.0.

You can use it like this:

```
    @GetMapping("user")
    String getUser(@SpringQueryMap User user);
```

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I added `@JsonProperty("na-me")` on top of the `User#name` is it expected that feign should make a request with encoded "na-me" param rather than "name" ? cause I thought is should but it doesn't and I am not sure if I should ask a separete question about it or it is just how feign works

Comment: @FilipKowalski Did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: @FilipKowalski - could solve the issue with @JsonProperty("na-me") in this situation?

Answer (score 12):

Working fine using `@QueryMap`

URL: **/api/v1/task/search?status=PENDING&size=20&page=0**

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>()
        parameters.put("status", "PENDING")
        parameters.put("size", "20")
        parameters.put("page", "0")
        def tasks = restClientFactory.taskApiClient.searchTasks(parameters)
```

Inside Client Interface

```
@RequestLine("GET /api/v1/task/search?{parameters}")
List<Task> searchTasks(@QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters)
```

Comment: I really like this approach. `@QueryMap` didn't worked for me instead replacing it with `@SpringQueryMap` does the job. Spring has some limitation while using `@QueryMap` for further reading: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/#feign-querymap-support

Answer (score 3):

With Spring feign client below works fine:

```
@GetMapping("/Groups?filter=displayName+Eq+{roleName}")
SCIMGroup isValidRole(@PathVariable(value = "roleName") String roleName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, as suggested by @Frank.Chang you can use @SpringQueryMap for this:

```
@GetMapping("user")
String getUser(@SpringQueryMap User user);
```

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("na-me")  // json property won't work
    private String name;
    private int age;
    ...
}
```

But remember, in this case @JsonProperty("na-me"), won't work for you. For that you will have to create a getter for the field and add @Param annotation from feign package on the getter. like this.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    ...
    @Param("na-me")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```