# how to pass Spring Pageable to FeignClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-feign, springdoc

as I wrote in this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/375
and in this SO question:
[Spring data Pageable does not work with feign client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115610/spring-data-pageable-does-not-work-with-feign-client/63116115#63116115)

I have some problems sending a Pageable object in a POST request containing a @requestbody element.

First I tried sending the Pageable embedded in my RequestBody since it was generated as example when using springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core.

Example:

```
@PostMapping("/search") public Page<HelloDto> searchHellos(@RequestBody HelloDto example, Pageable pageable)

{ "example": { "message": "string" }, "pageable": { "pageNumber": 0, "pageSize": 50, "offset": 10, "sort": { "sorted": false, }, "paged": true, } }
```

No I learned, that I can send it via Query parameter aswell and it will be parsed. The annotation that extracts the pageable into QueryParams is called org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject in SpringDoc.

```
@PostMapping("/search") public Page<HelloDto> searchHellos(@RequestBody HelloDto example, @ParameterObject Pageable pageable) { return helloCallerService.callHelloServiceClient(example, pageable); }
```

When I try to call a similar controller interface via feign like this client interface:

```
@PostMapping("/search") public Page<HelloDto> searchHellos(@RequestHeader("apiKey") String apiKey, @RequestBody HelloDto example, Pageable pageable);
```

The application won't start since the method "has too many body params".
I tried to annotate Pageable with @RequestParam but it won't be recognized / parsed.

My question is:

Can we use a custom AnnotatedParameterProcessor for e.g. @ParameterObject that flats out the ParameterObject and encodes it into the url query parameters?

How would you do that? Or is the AnnotatedParameterProcessor the wrong way? Do I maybe need an expander or anything?

Comment: did you manage to get this working? I've seen your answer about using @SpringQueryMap but in my case I need to modify some of the pageable queryparams.
Ex: sortField: DESC should become -sortField

Comment: Sorry, I just felt lucky that it parsed my Pageable correctly (at least it seems like it). I don't know how you get more control over this. 

Maybe look for a solution using Expander, Param annotation and RequestLine like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868680/feign-client-does-not-resolve-query-parameter

I'd also prefer a more generic solution which comes with confiuration options. Let me please know if you could resolve your issue.

Comment: Hmm, was looking into the custom AnnotatedParameterProcessor too but didn't have success yet. I'm also using the reactive-feign implementation and added a ticket there: https://github.com/Playtika/feign-reactive/issues/271

Comment: I've ended up with creating own object which extends from HashMap<String, String>. It can be used as a normal @RequestParam then. I've added a constructor which accepts a Pageable and puts the correct information into the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more related to feign usage than springdoc-openapi.
Using using `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.SpringQueryMap`, solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, my answer was deleted but this was exactly what I used.